# All three genders (der, die and das) at the same time?

Tags: gender, curiosity

I have noticed some words could be used in multiple genders.

- Das Eidotter
- Der Eidotter

Is there a word that is valid using all the three genders (der, die and das)?

Comment: You could reopen the question making an [edit] that makes it different from the one that yours is supposed to duplicate.

Comment: @c.p. I wont fix others failures. Polluter-pays-principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the same word (with same meaning, but gender-flexible) is meant, then

> Nutella

Verweisen kann ich auf [den Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/).

If the word is not required to be the same, then

> Band

accepts three genders. But this are three homographs words, which are not homophone. The feminine sounds different.

1. Die (Rock)band findet sie toll.
2. Der dritte Band der Enzyklopädie X fehlt.
3. Das Band der Kasse Nummer 6 ist kaputt.

Comment: Three words with ambiguous meanings. The letters are the same, as well as the order of the letters. But they point to different entitys, unlike Eidotter. But you can not change the genders between them. So the term "Der Band der Kasse Nummer 6 ist kaputt." is wrong. Unlike at Eidotter.

Comment: @PeterRader It's unlikely that you really get interchangable genders for the same noun. As I mentioned in my (now removed) comment, that might be dependent on regional idioms.